# 'Net Share' Some shares persistent after /delete

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, network-shares

Using **Net Share** command (as Administrator) I see a list of user shares.

However, some of these shares are persistent, and reappear after a reboot despite using the **/delete** suffix.

- Why do these shares reappear after reboots.
- What causes them to 'respawn'?
- How can I ensure they stay removed?

Answer (score 0):

If the shares were created by a program such as NFS, use it to unmount.

Otherwise, try this :

- Issue the `net use drive-letter /delete` command as Administrator
- Check the registry key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\Shares`
- If the shares are still there, delete them
- Reboot to check.

Comment: 'net use x: /delete' reports 'The network connection could not be found.' The registry key you mentioned contains no data. Perhaps I have a relevant service disabled?

Comment: Perhaps. But do you mean to say that `net share` shows shares that you cannot delete? Could you please add to your post a screenshot of these commands executing?